# Int Identity(1, 1) field in Sqlite Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I was at first using SQl Server for creating my Database, but I'am now using Sqlite for creating my Database, I did this because it only needed to be a very small database, but while converting the Database to SQLite I came across one problem, in SQL server I would just use :

```
ID int identity(1, 1)
```

for having an auto number field. This method can't be used in SQlite and I was wondering how I should do this, I already tried something like this:

```
create table settings(ID int autoincrement primary key, data text);
```

But that didn't help me. Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

The error I get is:

SQL Error: SQL Error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Comment: have you tried to apply solution described in this FAQ? http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1  namely `create table settings(ID integer primary key, b text);`

Comment: IDK why but for me `IDENTITY` works just fine in sqlite shell: `CREATE TABLE [Person]
(
   ID int IDENTITY(1, 1)  not null,
   CompositeID1 int not null,
   CompositeID2 int not null,

   constraint [pk_person] primary key (ID asc, CompositeID1 asc, CompositeID2 asc)
)`. My SQLite version `SQLite 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57 0c55d179733b46d8d0ba4d88e01a25e10677046ee3da1d5b1581e86726f2alt2
clang-8.0.8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't help how? Because in SQLite for WinRT (the latest version) the following works perfectly fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings(
Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Data TEXT);
```

Comment: I'm now finding some kind of error: SQL Error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an integer primary key

Comment: @Mobstaa Did you change anything or used the exact snipped I gave? Because the `Id` is - in fact - integer, so I see no reason why it would fail on this particular code piece. :) And as I mentioned, I use SQLite for 4 tables on WinRT application and each one of them has `int` autoincremented primary key, everything works fine...

Comment: it is not exactly, but the code I'm now using is: create table Settings(ID int primary key AUTOINCREMENT, Data TEXT); Does it has something to do with case sensitive?

Comment: @Mobstaa It has to do with `int`. There's no `int` type in SQLite, there's `integer` :) You have to type in `integer`, it's not case sensitive.